# Does sizeWithFont take autoshrink into account?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I've got some uilabels that have some annoyingly complicated positioning code to go along with them.

If I use sizeWithFont to size them based on their text, does that take the autoshrink property into account in finding that size?

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font minFontSize:(CGFloat)minFontSize actualFontSize:(CGFloat *)actualFontSize forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

In [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).  I think this will do what you want.